# How to set a cookie for a domain in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to set a cookie via PHP. The scenario is like this:

Domain is: `example.com`

There is one web page on sub-domain (my.example.com). My code is:

```
$value="I am looged in";
setcookie("TestCookie", $value,'','',".example.com");
echo "hello".$_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

but the result is only "hello" - the cookie is not getting set.

Comment: this works when use: setcookie("TestCookie", $value);

Comment: For easier cookie management, especially with regard to the "domain" property, you may use this: https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First two corrections to the actual call of [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php): Parameter 3 (`expired`) should be an integer value (the default value is 0); parameter four should be set to `'/'` to make the cookie valid for all subdirectories; the `setcookie` call should therefore look like this:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, 0, '/', ".example.com");
```

Then it should actually work the second time the script is called. To understand why it won't work the first time already, we have to dig in a little [into how cookies work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie); basically, Cookies are data sent from the server to the client, where the server says "send me this data **the next time you send me a request**". That's basically what setcookie is for: When the request is done and the client has received  and processed the page, the cookie as specified will have been created at the client; `$_COOKIE`, on the other hand, holds all values which **are in cookies already**, and which have been transmitted by the client along with the request - meaning that the first time the script is called, $_SESSION will actually still be empty, since the cookies will only be created once the client has received the scripts output.